# Communication WCF and silverlight5 with big object

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm new to WCF and Silverlight, there is an application with Silverlight client and WCF server, It had been working fine until I added a method which takes a big object as parameter. This object contains 93 properties of type int, bool, string, enum. When it blocks, WCF give error message like this:

`The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.`

No other message meaningful. All the *Timeout* and *Buffersize* in the config file are already set to the maximum value.

I have tried with an other object which contains less properties... I added one by one and it worked.

I found out when there are 72 properties(with enum, bool, string, int) it works, but when I add one more, it doesn't work any more.

I have been struggling during one week until right now, thanks a lot for helping me...

Comment: A sample of your code may help others to spot what's wrong.

Comment: thanks, it's the 1st time i ask question here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all the server-side quotas to the maximum, e.g. something like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
      </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

 <services>
  <service name="MyWcfService">
    <endpoint address="http://myservice..."
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
      name="MyBasicHttpBinding" contract="IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: It is already lik this     ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue
                }

Comment: If you're setting your quotas in code, please edit your question to include the entire code of how you're setting up your service.

Comment: NetTcpBinding tcpbindingResto = new etTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None {CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000),OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000), SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5000), ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000),MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue,
MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue, MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue,ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas{                   MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue, MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue,MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue,MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue}};

Comment: Thanks, but I also wanted to see the code where this binding you created (tcpbindingResto) is actually hooked up to your service.

Comment: var RestoSvc = new RestoServiceHost(RestoParams, typeof(Medialog.WCF.Internals.Wresto.Data.RestoService), new Uri(baseAddressHttp + RestoParams["Name"]), new Uri(baseAddressTcp + RestoParams["Name"]));
            RestoSvc.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Medialog.WCF.Internals.Wresto.Interfaces.IRestoService), tcpbinding, "");

Comment: Hmm... Don't see anything obvious that could be causing the problem. I can suggest 2 ways to try and debug this: (1) Turn on tracing on the server side, examine the trace to see what the exception was (or just run server in a debugger in "Stop on all exceptions" mode). (2) Switch both server and client to basicHttpBinding temporarily, see if the problem is still there (maybe the error threshold won't be exactly 72 properties anymore), and examine the server response in Fiddler with IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true on the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried this 2 suggestions, 1st, i add   <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="C:\log\Traces.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics> in configfile, but i didn' catch any trace, 2nd, it's always the samething ....

Answer (score 0):

In the end we found the solution, for those who have the same problem:
it was because that ny defaut, the MaxSessionSize(int the BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement)
of NetTcpBinding is maximun 2048, and we can not add any more, so we have to change into custombing with bigger MaxSessionSize.....